# python3.2.2 install easy_install error

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I want to learn python, so I get python3.2.2 and install it on ubuntu10 . As we know ubuntu have been preinstalled python2.6. So delete the old link, and create a new link to python3.2.2, everything is ok.

Now, I want to install easy_install, and I followed the steps on the website .

```
sudo wget http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py 
python ez_setup.py
```

and error occurs:

```
xx@ubuntu:/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages$ python ez_setup.py 
File "ez_setup.py", line 106
except pkg_resources.VersionConflict, e:
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

the message show: I am using python2.6 !!!  what's up, I have been liked to python3.2.2, so I checked the current pyton version.

```
xx@ubuntu:/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages$ python
Python 3.2.2 (default, Mar  9 2012, 07:38:22) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

it shows that I am now using python 3.2.2. So, how can I make a change to install ez_setup.py?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a version issue of easy_install. There is a similar thread in Serverfault. Check this one:

https://serverfault.com/questions/73741/easy-installing-under-different-python-version

It's a similar case, but the need is to install for older version.

Answer (score 0):

ez_setup.py does not work with python3.x
Revert back to python2.x and it should start working. (My experience from 64bit installation)